# Why do I get a file --library=ib... when I build a shared library?

Tags: g++, shared-libraries

I try to build a shared library with the following command:

g++ -Wall -shared -fPIC parallel_ppm.cpp -o -libparallel_ppm.so -std=c++11 -pthread

but instead of getting my libparallel_ppm.so I get this file --library=ibparallel_ppm.so and it can't be used as a shared library.

What's the error ?

Comment: Try `-o libparallel_ppm.so` (two words, one dash).

Comment: Indeed, that was the error. Thank you.